# how to join tables with a special sort/mysql-php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Hi there I have two tables:

```
1.teacher

id_t         fname_t   sname_t
1            john      smith
2            john2     smith2


2.student

id_s       id_t        fname_s   sname_s 
1           1          sarah1    fox1
2           1          sarah2    fox2
3           2          sarah3    fox3
4           2          sarah4    fox4
5           1          sarah5    fox5
```

I wana this result:

```
John Smith
  sarah1 fox1
  sarah2 fox2
  sarah5 fox5
John2 Smith2
  sarah3 fox3
  sarah4 fox4
```

I could sort teachers by this one:

```
function getGroupsForMenu()
{
    if($result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM teacher ORDER BY fname_t,lname_t ASC"))
    {
        $return = '';
        while($r = $result->fetch_object())
        {
            fname_t=htmlspecialchars($r->fname_t);
            lname_t=htmlspecialchars($r->lname_t);
            $return .= fname_t." ".lname_t."<br/>";

        }
        print $return; 
    }
}
```

And the result:

```
John  Smith
John2 Smith2
```

And My questoin:

How can I join 2 tables to get this result:
How can I join 2 tables to get this result:

```
John Smith
  sarah1 fox1
  sarah2 fox2
  sarah5 fox5
John2 Smith2
  sarah3 fox3
  sarah4 fox4
```

Comment: something like this: `code`SELECT *
    FROM teacher
    LEFT JOIN student
    ON teacher.id_t=student.id_t;`code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to use an `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT t.fname_t, t.sname_t, s.fname_s, s.sname_s FROM teacher AS t
    INNER JOIN student AS s ON t.id_t=s.id_t
    ORDER BY t.fname_t, t.sname_t, s.fname_s, s.sname_s
```

This will join the two tables using the teacher ID and order the results by the names returned.
You can format your display based on those results.

Answer (score 0):

The query

```
SELECT fname_t, sname_t, fname_s, sname_s 
  FROM teacher
  JOIN student ON teacher.id_t = student.id_t 
 ORDER BY fname_t,lname_t, fname_s, sname_s
```

will give you a result set looking like this:

```
John  Smith   sarah1 fox1
John  Smith   sarah2 fox2
John  Smith   sarah5 fox5
John2 Smith2  sarah3 fox3
John2 Smith2  sarah4 fox4
```

To format it indented as your question shows you'll need appropriate client-side php code detecting changes in the first two columns as it iterates through the result set rows.